# Is it possible to have wildcard in Gatsby matchPath without trailing slash?

Tags: gatsby

What I am trying to achieve here is this:

```
path: `/my-site-`,
matchPath: `/my-site-*`,
```

I am doing this in `gatsby-node.js` -> `createPage` and it doesn't work for me. So, my question is, should it work like this? Or am I doing nonsense here?

My goal here is once user goes to: `/my-site-1, /my-site-2, /my-site-3...` I want to show same page with those `1,2,3...` taken from URL.